# OnKeyPress JavaScript funcion on DotNetBrowser SetAttribute("value", "text")

Tags: javascript, dotnetbrowser

When I try to SetAttribute on `<Input>` element, the text doesn't invoke onkeypress JS function.
What should I do? I was thinking about using "sendkeys". But, it's not a good solution to handle with threads.

```
onkeypress="return filtraPassa(this, event, 'THIS_VAR_CHANGES_EVERYPAGELOAD');">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure a .NET handler for the `keypress` event, you should take a look at [DOM Events](https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110034-listening-to-dom-events).

The following sample code demonstrates how to add DOM event listener to the element:

```
DOMEventHandler domEvent = delegate(object sender, DOMEventArgs e)
{
     DOMEventType eventType = e.Type;
     Console.Out.WriteLine("handled event = " + eventType);
};

element.AddEventListener(DOMEventType.OnKeyPress, domEvent, false);
```

In addition, you need to take into account that modifying the element attribute may have no effect on its property:
[What is the difference between properties and attributes in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Comment: @tschallacka Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer with the necessary information.